# errors installing composer-cli

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, hyperledger-composer

I am having trouble getting composer-cli to install properly. I've tried uninstalling node and npm with both homebrew and other methods. I was getting an error pertaining to my python installation. So I went ahead and installed python2.7 and instructed npm to use that. This seemed to solve that particular error, but then others arose. If anybody has experience with this issue, I would greatly appreciate some assistance. Thank you!

Log File:

```
16859 verbose argv "/Users/jcole/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/bin/node" 
"/Users/jcole/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "composer-cli"
16860 verbose node v8.12.0
16861 verbose npm  v6.4.1
16862 error code ELIFECYCLE
16863 error errno 1
16864 error node-report@2.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
16864 error Exit status 1
16865 error Failed at the node-report@2.2.1 install script.
16865 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
16866 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

terminal:

```
[~]$ npm install -g composer-cli
/Users/jcole/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/bin/composer -> /Users/jcole/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/cli.js

> dtrace-provider@0.8.7 install /Users/jcole/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider
> node-gyp rebuild || node suppress-error.js

gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/local/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:336:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:561:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/jcole/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/bin/node" "/Users/jcole/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jcole/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

> fsevents@1.2.4 install /Users/jcole/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/jcole/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> node-report@2.2.1 install /Users/jcole/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/local/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:336:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:561:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/jcole/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/bin/node" "/Users/jcole/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jcole/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-report@2.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-report@2.2.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jcole/.npm/_logs/2018-09-18T01_49_06_082Z-debug.log
[~]$
```

Comment: share your docker file you missing some libraries in your dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's still installing using `python3`. Can you try completely removing `python3` or disabling from your shell?

This is the result based on the error:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];'
2.7.15
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];'
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: As mentioned above, you need to check you're using correct level of python - and comply with the pre-requisites for Hyperledger Composer -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs

Comment: I tried forcing it to use 2.7, but completely uninstalling python3 seems to have solved the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

OSX (Darwin 17.7.0) ships with python 2.7 and lot of the underlying scripts used by `npm` expect that and use "Old Style" string formatting with "%". This does not work if you have upgraded out of the late-2000s to Python 3+.

This problem will keep popping up every time you (re)install a component with this issue. Repeatedly un-installing and reinstalling python is very frustrating.

Workaround: Temporarily put OSX's original python executable at the front of $PATH, run you `npm install`. Its usually in `/usr/bin` so try:

```
$ GOODPATH=$PATH
$ export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

```
npm install ....
```

```
$ export PATH=$GOODPATH
$ python --version
Python 3.7.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the same problem on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine by =>

Installing pre-requisites at https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html

which says->

```
curl -O https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/prereqs-ubuntu.sh
```

then
    chmod u+x prereqs-ubuntu.sh
and at last =>

```
./prereqs-ubuntu.sh
```

then restart your terminal and try the installation =>

```
npm install -g composer-cli@0.20
```

without su or sudo. I hope this helps :):)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occurred while running npm install -g composer-cli on macOS Mojave(10.14.3) 
node version : v8.15.1, 
nvm version : 0.33.0, 
npm version : 6.4.1

terminal :

```
MacBook-Air:~ shantanu$ npm install -g composer-cli@0.20
/Users/shantanu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/bin/composer -> /Users/shantanu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/cli.js

> dtrace-provider@0.8.7 install /Users/shantanu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider
> node-gyp rebuild || node suppress-error.js

gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /anaconda3/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:281:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:336:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:561:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/shantanu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/bin/node" "/Users/shantanu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/shantanu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider
gyp ERR! node -v v8.15.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

> fsevents@1.2.7 install /Users/shantanu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
[fsevents] Success: "/Users/shantanu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node" is installed via remote

> node-report@2.2.1 install /Users/shantanu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /anaconda3/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:281:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/shantanu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/bin/node" "/Users/shantanu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/shantanu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report
gyp ERR! node -v v8.15.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-report@2.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-report@2.2.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/shantanu/.npm/_logs/2019-03-16T10_22_33_184Z-debug.log
```

Error occurred because it was installing using python3. Uninstalling python3 was not a good option so I temporarily changed python default path to OSX's original pyhton path

```
  $ GOODPATH=$PATH
    $ export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
    $ python --version
    Python 2.7.10
```

And then installed composer-cli using commands mentioned in https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html

And after successfully installing composer-cli changed the default python path as it was before.

```
$ export PATH=$GOODPATH
$ python --version
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try installing with `--unsafe-perm`...

It worked for me...